# How to pass Observable object with Button action (OnTap) to a new view

Tags: swiftui, combine

I would like to know how to pass my published values from UserSettings to my ThirdView only when the buttons on the secondView are selected..

I need to published values to be displayed in a text on the thirdView when overlay is selected and then not show when overlay isn't on.

Is this even possible?? I have been trying for three weeks but can't seem to make it work. I can pass one but I can't seem to show more or delete it when overlay is not on.

Thanks in advance.

**UserSettings**

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class UserSettings: ObservableObject {

    @Published var username: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(username, forKey: "username")
        }
    }

    @Published var email: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")
        }
    }

    @Published var firstname: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(firstname, forKey: "firstname")
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.username = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "username") as? String ?? ""
        self.email = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email") as? String ?? ""
        self.firstname = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "firstname") as? String ?? ""
    } 
}
```

**ContentView**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("username")
                    TextField("Enter userNmae", text: $userSettings.username)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Email")
                    TextField("Enter Email", text: $userSettings.email)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }
    
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Text("fsfsdfgsdfg")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondView**

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
  
        VStack {
            Group {
                Button(
                    action: { self.isTapped1.toggle() }
                ){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: self.isTapped1 ? 3 : 0))
                }
                
                Button(
                    action: { self.isTapped1.toggle() }
                ){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: self.isTapped2 ? 3 : 0))
                }
            }
                
            Button(action: 
                { self.isTapped1.toggle() }){
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: self.isTapped3 ? 3 : 0))
```

**ThirdView**

Help

Comment: I don't understand the aim of your code, but to pass observable object to multy views, use @EnviromentObject

Comment: If you want to pass the data of the ObservableObject, but not the actual object, you could  put a parameter into the next view and pass the data from the ObservedObject into that. You couldn't change the object, but you could use the data. If you want to be able to change the data, you could pass it in as either an ObservedObject or and EnvironmentObject.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, I am extremely new to SwiftUI and coding  in general but  I will  look into how put a parameter into the next view and what that actual means. haha. thanks again.